# I need help in understanding the relationship between client certificate authentication and loginservice using jetty embedded

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, client-certificates

I am using jetty 7 embedded in in my Java WebApp project.

I have setup SSL and the next step is to handle Client Certificate authentication.
In the web.xml I have specified:

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
<realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>EntireApp</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>allAuthenticated</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Below is the code in the startserver routine:

```
SslSelectChannelConnector ssl_connector = new SslSelectChannelConnector();
    ssl_connector.setPort(Integer.valueOf(httpPort1));
    SslContextFactory cf = ssl_connector.getSslContextFactory();
    cf.setKeyStore(sslProperties.getKeyStore());
    cf.setKeyStorePassword(sslProperties.getKeyPassword());
    cf.setTrustStore(sslProperties.getTrustStore());
    cf.setTrustStorePassword(sslProperties.getTrustStorePassword());
    cf.setNeedClientAuth(true);

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{ connector0,  ssl_connector });

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setDescriptor("WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    context.setResourceBase("WebContent");
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

    SecurityHandler secHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();

    //Authenticator authenticator = new ClientCertAuthenticator();
    Authenticator authenticator = new DummyAuthenticator();


  //probably I need something different, but what ? 
    LoginService loginService = new HashLoginService("Test Realm", "d:/downloads/test.properties");

    secHandler.setRealmName("Test Realm");
    secHandler.setLoginService(loginService);

    secHandler.setAuthenticator(authenticator);

    context.setSecurityHandler(secHandler);

    server.setHandler(context);

    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My question is what loginservice should I use in conjunction with the ClientCertAuthenticator ?
Or if that is not possible, what would be the best way to implement my own (DummyAuthenticator) ?

In the code above I am using the DummyAuthenticator which just implements the Authenticator interface, but the servletRequest in the validateRequest method always has an empty parameterMap where I am expecting

Comment: OK the javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate is a request attribute not a parameter and I do get this on in my DummyAuthenticator.validateRequest method...

Comment: But now that I have the certificate how does this relate to the loginservice ? Do I need that at all ?